# PKI.JS: Cannot use import statement outside a module (TypeScript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules

I searched for this error and found dozens of answers, but none worked for me. I'm writing microservices using serverless framework with node.js (v12.22.7) & typescript (v4.2.4)

Everything worked so far, until I tried to add [PKIJS](https://pkijs.org/) as a dependency

My code snippet:

```
/// <reference types="@types/pkijs" />
import OCSPResponse from "pkijs/src/OCSPResponse";

const ocspRespSimpl = new OCSPResponse({ schema: asn1.result });
```

fails with **SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Node 12",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "ES2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "ES2019"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "composite": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "__tests__/**/*"]
}
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "@services/admin-apis",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist ./.serverless",
    "lint": "eslint -c ../../../.eslintrc.js --fix ./src/**/*.ts",
    "prebuild": "yarn lint",
    "build": "tsc -b",
    "package": "sls package",
    "deploy": "sls deploy",
    "test": "jest -c ../../../jest.config.js --rootDir . --passWithNoTests --colors --silent"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/pkijs": "^0.0.12",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@peculiar/x509": "^1.6.0",
    "@peculiar/webcrypto": "^1.2.2",
    "@peculiar/asn1-ocsp": "^2.0.38",
    "pkijs": "^2.2.1",
  }
}
```

Obviously, I cannot modify PKIJS, how can I make it so that I can use that dependency? I tried already adding `"type": "module"` to package.json but it didn't work, also tried several combinations of *target* and *module* in tsconfig, didn't work either.